# Is it possible to have a youtube video play when a certain CSS is picked?

Tags: javascript, css, html, youtube, embed

I'm Looking for a way to have different youtube videos appear and play when a certain CSS is picked, from a drop down menu. I was thinking JavaScript could be used to check for the CSS.

Adding to the html header of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="=./javascript/playvid4css.js"></script>
```

eg/ CSS

red.css
blue.css

[Red plays](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kvWClaJKd8)
[Blue plays](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNF_P281Uu4)

Maybe adding a `div` file to the html for where the video would appear.

```
<div id="yvideo"></div>
```

## #

youtube embeding code.

old embed code:

```
<object width="420" height="315">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/N9ync7sLSd4?version=3&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;rel=0"></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/N9ync7sLSd4?version=3&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="420" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
</object>
```

youtube iframe code: (possibly the code they will be trying to use for all videos in the future)

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/N9ync7sLSd4?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

## #

Any ideas how to connect JavaScript to the CSS so the different youtube would appear,
or is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `document.styleSheets` - it is an array (ordered list) of stylesheets associated with your webpage. You can find a reference here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/stylesheet

The `disabled` property states whether the given stylesheet has been applied or not.

So, you could iterate over the stylesheets and when you come upon the red or blue, check if they're applied (not disabled).

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++)
    if (document.styleSheets[i].href == "myRedStyleSheet.css" && 
        !document.styleSheets[i].disabled) {

            // code for the red stylesheet

    } else if (document.styleSheets[i].href == "myBlueStyleSheet.css" && 
               !document.styleSheets[i].disabled) {

            // code for the blue stylesheet
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

im assuming ur changing the included css using a dropdown.. if yes.. then on the same selected event on which ur reading the changed value and changing the .CSS file u can also remove the old Iframe and add a new.. that would be easy.. sply by using JQUERY

Comment: plz help me improve and leave a comment describing ur reason to down vote when ever ur doing it.. thankx

Comment: The spelling, no code, no examples, nothing stands out, so no formats, i wouldnt even read this post.